# Java - How to get count of rows from CSV file which is inside zip file

Tags: java

I have a multiple zip files at a particular location. 
Each Zip file consists of 1 CSV file inside it. I have tried below code to read each zip file and get the count of CSV which is inside the zip and finally, I am printing sum of rows from each file. The code is executing without error but final value which is printed is invalid. Any help will be appreciated.

File1.csv   -- which is inside File1.Zip

[image]

File2.csv  -- which is inside File2.Zip

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String archivePath = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\";
        String FileName ="";
        LineNumberReader reader = null;
        long totalLines = 0;


        try (DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(archivePath), "*.zip"))
        {

            for (Path entry : dir)
            {

                Path sourceCsvFileName = entry.getFileName();
                FileName = sourceCsvFileName.toString();
                //  System.out.println(" File name: "+ FileName);   // prints FileName Eg: File1.zip , File2.zip



                // Below logic to Read number of lines for each iterated CSV which is inside zip file  (NOTE: Stop reading on encountering empty row)


                reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(archivePath + FileName)));
                while ((reader.readLine()) != null);

                totalLines = totalLines  + reader.getLineNumber();





                reader.close();

            }

            System.out.println("Total sum of rows from all files-> " + totalLines);   // expected o/p (5+2):  7  actual o/p : 13

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Your entry is a file in the archivePath. entry.getFileName() will give you the name of that file, you push it to FileName (please consider the java naming conventions...). You will open a new FIle for that fileName and a Reader for that File. The LineNumberReader will read I don't know what, but most definitely not the number of lines in a file that is inside tha file you have at hand (which is most likely a zip). You will need to extract that zip file first.

Comment: @Bluddymarri Code prints expected output when I am reading the count of rows directly from CSV files. i.e. File Mask as *.csv. So LineNumberReader is giving me the number of rows in CSV file. But results in the incorrect results while getting count without extracting (*.zip). Is there a way to get a count of rows in CSV files without extracting Zip.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use ZipFile / ZipEntry classes to read files inside zips.
The below code should do what you need :

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(archivePath), "*.zip")) {
       for (Path entry : dir) {
          ZipFile zipFile =  new ZipFile(entry.getFileName().toString());
          Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
          while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
               ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
               reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry),"UTF-8"));
               while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        totalLines++;
               }          
          }
          reader.close();
       }
       System.out.println("Total sum of rows from all files-> " + totalLines);   // expected o/p (5+2):  7  actual o/p : 13
} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: totalLines++ just results in a count of total Files in my case it prints 2
I don't want the count of total files, I want the count of rows from each CSV file which is inside zip file.

Comment: Thanks, @funkyjelly updated code worked. But it worked only for Sample files which I had posted in my post. For actual CSV Files that are downloaded from Salesforce in zip format, count displayed is incorrect. Not Sure but I think this must be an issue with CSV row separator, also data for each column is enclosed in double-quotes (Text Enclosure) Is there a way to deal with this and get correct count?

Comment: @Vikas can you post some sample content of these other CSV files ?